# How to not render concrete components in render method in REACT 17.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, components, render

In my render method of my component I create instances of a dozen other components, some of them such as headers, dropdowns, filters need not to be rendered after each update of its parent component.
I could make a flag set to true that would be reset in componentDidMount() to false but I thought there could be a better, nice, cleaner way.
Here I present my component's render method

```
render() {
        console.log("som v render weather list")


        const currentWeathers = this.getWeathersOnSpecificPage()
        const filters = <FiltersComponent key={nanoid()} temperatureUnits = {this.state.temperature.units} countries = {this.state.countries}
        descriptions = {this.state.descriptions} onChangeMethod={this.onChangeFilter} />

        const pagination = <Pagination key={nanoid()} currentPage={this.state.currentPage} showPages={this.state.showPages}
        itemsPerPage = {this.state.itemsPerPage} totalItems = {this.state.weathers.length} paginate={this.paginate}/>

        const temperatureDropdown = temperatureDropdownList( (units, abbreviation ) => {
            this.setState({"temperature": {"units" : units, "abbreviation" : abbreviation}})
        })

        let container= [temperatureDropdown, filters, pagination]

        if (this.state.weathers)
            container.push(<table key={nanoid()} className="weatherTable">
                {this.header()}
                {this.mainBody(currentWeathers, this.state.temperature)}
            </table>
            )

        return (
            <div className="container">
             {container}
            </div>
        )
         
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React.PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)
This way, the component will make a shallow compare and will rerender only if something has changed.

If you have a functional component you should  [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

Comment: Ok so I read in your link that to use it I extend my class Component with React.PureComponent.
What do if I am dealing with function components.